# make post request with dictionary and utf-8 in swift

Tags: json, swift, utf-8

I need to make a post request to send a dictionary in the body of post request that needs to be encoded with utf-8, 
I tried this below but it gives an error:

```
  let DicObject: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        DicObject.setValue("cf", forKey: "a")
        DicObject.setValue("", forKey: "scs")
        DicObject.setValue("Uploads/" + nameOfFile, forKey:"p")
```

when I try to make

```
 request.httpMethod = "POST"
      //  request.httpBody = jsonObject as Data
        request.addValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")
```

it doesn't work, Does anyone know how to convert `jsonObject` encode to utf-8

Thanks.

Comment: Convert your Json object to string and pass in POST request.

Comment: It doesnt work, the erro message: Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' to type 'NSString' in coercion. and tried like this : let convert = (DicObject as NSString).utf8String

Comment: Please try my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `jsonObject` to `data` using `JSONSerialization`

```
if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted)
     request.httpBody = data
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert in Normal bytes? Not a json

Comment: @Steven Yes, `String.init(bytes: bytes, encoding: .utf8)` OR `Data.init(bytes: bytes)` pick whatever is suitable for you.

Comment: thanks. but I get the error :Cannot invoke 'Data.Type.init' with an argument list of type '(bytes: NSMutableDictionary)' when I try  let convert = Data.init(bytes: DicObject).

Comment: `DicObject` is not byte so compiler will not allow you pass it as bytes. Is there any reason to not use the `JSONSerialization` to get `data`?

Comment: Because the server not support Json, I need to convert it only in utf-8 and send it.

Comment: Then why are you creating `DicObject`?. You should make a simple string(`let string = "a=cf&scs=""&p=Upload/\(nameOfFile)"`) and send that by converting into data.

Comment: I tried with simple string but it didn't work, because I need to sperate them with "," not with &. for example : let string = "a=cf,scs="",p=Upload/\(nameOfFile)" but it didn't work.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 let jsonData: NSData

 do {
        jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: DicObject, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions()) as NSData
        let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
        print("json string = \(jsonString)")
        print("json jsonData = \(jsonData)")

   } catch _ {
           print ("JSON Failure")
   }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Alamofire method

```
      mydict = [:] // Your parameters here

      if let theJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(
            withJSONObject: mydict,
            options: []) {
            let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData,
                                     encoding: .ascii)
            multipartFormData.append((theJSONText?.data(using: .utf8)!)!, withName: "bulkData")
        }
```